# Re-arranging Dataframe columns based on substrings in column names

Tags: python, string, sorting, dataframe

I have a dataframe, `df`, that has values of two characters over quarters of the year. [Q1 = Jan, Feb, Mar; Q2 = Apr, May, Jun, ...etc].

The quarters are the previous four quarters trailing the current quarter (ex. if Current Quarter = Q3 17, quarters measured are `Q3 16`, `Q4 16`, `Q1 17`, `Q2 17`).

```
Quarter      Q1 17   Q2 17  Q3 16  Q4 16
Character
Sonic         10.0   6.0    19.0    3.0
Shadow        5.0    5.0    7.0     23.0
```

I would like to reorder the columns in a time applied manner, `Q3 16`, `Q4 16`, `Q1 17`, `Q2 17`, to get this:

```
Quarter      Q3 16   Q4 16  Q1 17  Q2 17
Character
Sonic         19.0   3.0    10.0    6.0
Shadow        7.0    23.0   5.0     5.0
```

I've thought about sorting by substring where the year is contained. But is there a cleaner and quicker way to do this?

### **[EDIT]**

For clarification, I created substrings of the year:

```
columns = list(scar_pivot.columns.values)
sort_columns_years = [int(c[3:5]) for c in columns]
sort_columns_years=
[17, 17, 16, 16]
```

Since this code in question is used periodically over time, a user would be measuring different quarters depending on when the code is used. (ex. Current quarter is  Q2 17, there would be three values of `16` and one value of `17` in `sort_columns_years`, for Q2-4 16, and Q1 17.

After sorting `sort_columns_years`, I am thinking I can use `count` to measure how many of a smaller value exists, to do something in the case of hree quarters in the preceding year like this:

```
new_list = []
`if sort_columns_years.count(16) == 3:
     sort_quarters = ['Q2','Q3','Q4','Q1']
     for each in range(0,len(sort_quarters)):
        new_list.append(sort_column_years[each] + sort_column_years(sort_quarters[each]))
```

to get

`new_list = ['Q2 16', 'Q3 16', 'Q4 16', 'Q1 17']`

but I don't know how to do something similar avoiding hard coding `16` or `17`.

Comment: @florence-y your output does not align with the input. I got what you want. Edit your expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though I believe there would be some way to do it using series or numpy
But, if you think the problem can be solved if the year component is brought in front of the quater like `16Q1` and then sorting would be easy and more meaningful. Here is the example:

```
def restructure(l):
    temp_lis=[]
    for i in l:
        temp=i.split(" ")
        temp_lis.append(temp[1] +' '+temp[0] )
    return temp_lis

a=['Q1 17', 'Q2 17','Q3 16','Q4 16']
new_list=[]

new_list=sorted(restructure(a))
final=restructure(new_list)

print(final)
```

Output:

```
['Q3 16', 'Q4 16', 'Q1 17', 'Q2 17']
```

If you need to define your df with columns.

```
df[[final]] # should be enough
```